# java regEx, really confused

Tags: java, regex

Please help in developing a regEx expression. My requirement is to validate the following string,

```
String="asdasd|adajjsd|asas,asdas|asda|sd";
```

pattern id [String]separatedByPipe[String]separatedByPipe[String]

ex:`String="asdasd|adajjsd|asas"`.

The above pattern is repeated, separated by comma, if there are multiple Strings
ex:`String="asdasd|adajjsd|asas,asdas|asda|sd"`;

I can make an assumption that the pattern is going to repeat only max 3 times, ie at max 2 commas in my String.

Attached my testClass

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestReg {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //String regex = "[a-z]+\\|[a-z]+,[a-z]+\\|[a-z]*";
    String regex = "([a-z]\\|[a-z]\\|[a-z]\\,?)+";
    //String regex = "[a-z]+\\|re{ 1}[a-z]+\\|re{ 1}[a-z]+[a-z]+\\|[a-z]+\\|[a-z]*";
    //String regex = "[a-z](|)[a-z](,)[a-z](|)[a-z]";
    //String pattern="([a-z]+@)([a-z]+)(\\.[a-z]+)"; 
    //String inputString1 = "shdifhsdui-asdasd,shdifhsdui|abc";


    //String inputString1 = "";//failed
    String inputString1 = "asdasd|adajjsd|asas,asdas|asda|sd";//success
    //String inputString1 = "asdasd|adasd-asdas|asdasd";//success
    //String inputString1 = "asdasd|adasd|asassa,asdas|asdasd";//failed
    Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(inputString1);
    boolean result = matcher1.find();          
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

}

hi all ,

```
System.out.println ("asdasd|adajjsd|asa,s|sad|sdas,asd|as|as|da".matches ("([a-z]*\\|[a-z]*\\|[a-z]*\\,?)+"));
```

working like charm. So why the same is not working in my above class. Kindly help.Am using jdk1.5

Comment: You do not need to backslash-escape a `,` as it has no special meaning in regex.

Answer (score 1):

This java regex will match your requirements:

```
"[a-z]+(\\|[a-z]+){2}(,[a-z]+(\\|[a-z]+){2})*"
```

That will validate the input, but to extract the parts I would simply use `split()` on commas, then for each part split on pipe:

```
for (String group : input.split(",")) {
    String[] parts = group.split("\\|");
    // do something with the parts
}
```

It's just two lines of code to get to your data.

Comment: hi this is failing for the below string.  String inputString1 = "asdasd|adajjsd|asas,asdas|asda|sd|";  I have added an extra pipe at the last.I am not in a situation to use the split method.

Comment: Your answer is correct if using ".matches()" method.I have edited the question. Please have a look. matcher() and matches(), giving different outputs.

Comment: I can get split to work, but with your example, are you expecting a blank field at the end?

Answer (score 0):

change the String regex to

```
String regex = "([a-z]*\\|[a-z]*\\|[a-z]*\\,?)+";
```

and then try

```
    String inputString1 = "asdasd|adajjsd|asas,asdas|asda|sd";
    String regex = "([a-z]*\\|[a-z]*\\|[a-z]*\\,?)+";
    Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(inputString1);
    boolean result = matcher1.find();          

    System.out.println(inputString1.substring(matcher1.regionStart(), matcher1.regionEnd()));
```

Comment: hi this is failing for the below string.  String inputString1 = "asdasd|adajjsd|asas,asdas|asda|sd|";  I have added an extra pipe at the last.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please have a look. matcher() and matches(), giving different outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Your can validate it using this regex

```
^(?!.*,$)[a-z]+(\\|[a-z]+,?)*$
```

Comment: @SujeeshSValath you should specify all the valid and invalid combinations in your question..else no one would be able to help you

Comment: I have edited the question. Please have a look. matcher() and matches(), giving different outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Split on `,`, then on `|`

```
String[] terms = string.split(",");
for (String term : terms) {
    String[] parts = term.split("\\|");
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question. Please have a look. matcher() and matches(), giving different outputs.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to test above entire static string as one string then this regex pattern will help you .. but if you want to test the different string seprated by "|" then you need to take other regex pattern.

String regex = "([a-z]{6}\|[a-z]{7}\|[a-z]{4}\,[a-z]{5}\|[a-z]{2}?)+";

Comment: hi this is failing for the below string.  String inputString1 = "asdasd|adajjsd|asas,asdas|asda|sd|";  I have added an extra pipe at the last.

Answer (score 0):

Please try if this helps:

```
String regex = "[a-z]*\\|*,*[a-z]*";
```

And rest of the code should not need change.

Comment: failing for  String inputString1 = "asdasd|adajjsd|asas,asdas|asda|sd|"

Comment: Please try this String regex = "[a-z]*\\|*,*[a-z]*\\|*";. Also please specify the combination that are possible from your requirements perspective. I go by Anirudh's point on this.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please have a look. matcher() and matches(), giving different outputs.

Comment: Pattern you are trying to match in your code is:

one character|one character|one character,one character|one character|one character

When you put * after [a-z] it matches 0 or more occurence of the character so it works when you use matches of String class